# Best approach to simple proxy on BIZTALK

Tags: web-services, soap, proxy, biztalk

I have to develop simple proxy SOAP WS that receive and pass trough requests from client (A)  to destination (B) and send back responses to A without any logic inside.

I wonder is there simpler soulution than mine which is 1 orchiestration contains one receive and one send port with the same schema based on WSDL from B.

Maybe there is better universal approach to that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply have a Send Port that subscribes to the Receive Port, e.g `BTS.ReceivePort = ReceivePortName`.   The response on the two way Send Port will automatically be routes back to the Receive Port