# Hosting the endpoint in the BizTalk process using non UTF-8 encoding

Tags: wcf, biztalk

There is a problem with encoding using WCF detailed described here : blog post
[WCF: Text Message Encoding and ISO-8859-1 Encoding](https://blogs.msmvps.com/paulomorgado/2007/04/25/wcf-text-message-encoding-and-iso-8859-1-encoding/)

I'm getting similar error in response :

> A message sent to adapter "WCF-BasicHttp" on send port "XXXX" with URI "http://XXXXXXXX:8080/index.php" is suspended.
>
> Error details: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/xml; **charset=ISO-8859-1** of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

I'd like to create a simple proxy WS in BizTalk Environment. I created 1 Receive Location using WCF-BasicHttp / WCF-Custom (neither worked) adapter and send port (SOAP WCF-BasicHttp). Send port is subscribing Receive Location as mentioned here:

[Best approach to simple proxy on BIZTALK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039564/best-approach-to-simple-proxy-on-biztalk)

I created endpoint in the BizTalk process mentioned here: Codit Blog [Hosting WCF HTTP receive location inside BizTalk, without using IIS.](https://www.codit.eu/blog/hosting-wcf-http-receive-location-inside-biztalk-without-using-iis/)

I cannot set other textEncoding than UTF-8, while trying to set ISO-8859-1 I get the error:

> "The text encoding ISO-8859-1 used in the text message format is not supported. Parameter name: encoding"

Is there any way to run this using some custom encoders in BizTalk environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it myself.
I deleted textMessageEncoding binding from Receive and Send WCF-Custom adapter

[image: textMessageEncoding]

and instead of it I put customMessageEncoder binding with soap11 and proper iso encoding. Note that httpTransport should be last on binding list.

[image: customMessageEncoding]